# Realtime Database или Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-database, firestore

Изначально я создал андроид проект на realtime, но сейчас увидев прайсы немного занервничал... в принципе я немногое успел написать, очень ли трудно будет перенести на firestore или на другую базу данных, ибо как мне кажется у firebase цены высокие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял - Обе БД "в меру" бесплатные.
Перенос данных зависит от сложности самой структуры БД. Получить json файл со всеми данными довольно просто - [image: Вот так]
Остается только "запушить" их в новую БД.
Функционал в firestore больше. Но некоторых вещей не хватает.